# F#zzBuzz: Learning the easy way

Tags: f#, fizzbuzz

So I made a quick programme in F# to do FizzBuzz, I'm trying to learn more languages, so I figured I'd do something functional for a change. (Haskell is also on the list.)

FizzBuzz is pretty self-explanatory: every third value print `Fizz`, every fifth print `Buzz` (possible both if it's a multiple of 3 and 5).

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let fizzBuzzSequence = seq {
        for value in 1..100 do
            let valueMod3 = value % 3
            let valueMod5 = value % 5

            if valueMod3 = 0 && valueMod5 = 0 then yield "FizzBuzz"
            else if valueMod3 = 0 && valueMod5 <> 0 then yield "Fizz"
            else if valueMod3 <> 0 && valueMod5 = 0 then yield "Buzz"
            else yield value.ToString()
    }
    for value in fizzBuzzSequence do printfn "%s" value
    0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I don't see a real need for these two variables:

> ```
> let valueMod3 = value % 3
> let valueMod5 = value % 5
> ```

To me, they just seem a little unnecessary. In fact, writing out the expression `value % 3` or `value % 5` takes the exact same amount of keystrokes as writing `valueMod3` or `valueMod5`.

Next, I'd highly recommend that you get into the habit of using [Match Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx) rather than plain old `if` statements, as it's more functional, and will give you more benefits, like [Pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx), over `if` statements. This means that this small chunk of `if` statements:

> ```
> if valueMod3 = 0 && valueMod5 = 0 then yield "FizzBuzz"
> else if valueMod3 = 0 && valueMod5 <> 0 then yield "Fizz"
> else if valueMod3 <> 0 && valueMod5 = 0 then yield "Buzz"
> else yield value.ToString()
> ```

Would become a Match Expression, like this:

```
match n with
| n when n % 3 = 0 && n % 5 = 0 -> yield "FizzBuzz"
| n when n % 3 = 0 -> yield "Fizz"
| n when n % 5 = 0 -> yield "Buzz"
| _ -> yield n.ToString()
```

After all these improvements to your code, I ended up with the following, working code:

```
let fizzbuzzSequence = seq { 
    for n in 1 .. 100 do
        match n with
        | n when n % 3 = 0 && n % 5 = 0 -> yield "FizzBuzz"
        | n when n % 3 = 0 -> yield "Fizz"
        | n when n % 5 = 0 -> yield "Buzz"
        | _ -> yield n.ToString()
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    for item in fizzbuzzSequence do
        System.Console.WriteLine(item)

    0
```

Comment: Variables do not exist solely for saving keystrokes ... or even primarily for that purpose.

Comment: @phoog I'm aware of that. There's simply no point in creating those two variables though, so I pointed that out.

Comment: There could be a point, though likely not in this context: Division is expensive.  The variables allow you to avoid repetitious division.

Answer (score 3):

I have some general comments:

- *Why limit to a predefined sequence?* – You could pass a range to your sequence generator, which would allow for you to generate a random sequence. Like in:

  ```
  let my_sequence range = seq { 
      for value in range do 
         ...
   }
  ```
- *Allow for other fizzbuzz words* – Instead of hard coding the 3 & 5 (and the combination of 15), use a dictionary to allow for extending the choices. This could either be a [mutable dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/fsharp/fsharp_mutable_dictionary.htm), or you could make it non-mutable dict like in:

  ```
  fizzbuzzWords = dict[3, "Fizz"; 5, "Buzz"; 7, "Boom"]
  ```
- *Concatenate parts to avoid repeating module operations* – In your code you do `% 3` and `% 5`, and the extraneous `% 15`. If you instead did the different modulos one by one, you could concatenate the parts together:

  ```
  fizzbuzzParts value |> String.concat ""
  ```
- *Move bits and pieces out of `[<EntryPoint>]`* – Don't do *everything* in the main function, keep that succint and to the point.

<del>I'll leave it to the reader to actually implement these suggestions!</del> Why should the reader have all the fun? Here is a working example (see [code at repl.it](https://repl.it/B6E7)):

```
open System.Collections.Generic

// Non-mutable dict of fizzbuzz words
let fizzbuzzWords = dict[3, "Fizz"; 5, "Buzz"; 7, "Boom"]

// Generates single complete fizzbuzz word, or nothing if not a fizzbuzz number
let fizzbuzzParts number =  seq {
    for pair in fizzbuzzWords do
        if number % pair.Key = 0 then yield (pair.Value)
    }

// Generator for a sequence
let fizzbuzzSequence range = seq {
    for value in range do
        let fizzPart =  fizzbuzzParts value |> String.concat ""
        yield if fizzPart <> "" then fizzPart else value.ToString()
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    for value in fizzbuzzSequence [ 104 .. 121 ] do
        printf "%s " value 

    printfn ""
    0
```

In stead of using a mutable Dictionary, I here use non-mutable dictionary, and some helper generators. This produces the following output:

```
104 FizzBuzzBoom 106 107 Fizz 109 Buzz Fizz Boom 113 Fizz Buzz 116 Fizz 118 Boom FizzBuzz 121
```

I wasn't entirely satisfied with this solution, even though I haven't programmed in [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23) before, and have been googling my way to all the bits and pieces to compile this answer! :-)

So I kept on googling, and landed on this alternate solution (see [updated code](https://repl.it/B6E7/5) for following and various other variants):

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let fizzbuzz number =
   seq {                          // Build sequence of word parts
        for pair in dict [3, "Fizz";
                          5, "Buzz";
                          7, "Boom"] do
            if number % pair.Key = 0 then  // If modulo is 0 ...
                yield pair.Value           // ... yield a word part
    }                             
    |> String.concat ""           // Concatenate the word parts
    |> function                   // Do a match on the word
       | "" -> number.ToString()  //   If nothing, use number
       | word -> word             //   else use the word


[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 

    { 104 .. 121 }
    |> Seq.iter (fizzbuzz >> printf "%s ")

    printfn ""
    0
```

The output is the same, but this version is somewhat cleaner and a little more functional. This solution focuses more on getting a single `fizzbuzzWord` based on an inline list of [fizzbuzz](/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) words.